# Center all the content inside div using Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to center all the content inside a div with Bootstrap 3, however it's not working, it's centering only the textarea, not the content between the `<span>` tag, what's wrong with my code?

```
<style type="text/css">
    .col-centered{
        float: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }  
</style>


<div class="row">

     <div class="col-lg-8 col-centered"> <textarea class="form-control" rows="10"> </textarea>  

         <span>
          Informações: 
          <i id="demo">
             <div class="label label-default label-dismissible">Não iniciado</div>
          </i>
          | Carregadas: 
          <div id="carregada" class="label label-primary label-dismissible">0</div>
          | Testadas: 
          <div id="testado" class="label label-info label-dismissible">0</div>
          | Aprovadas: 
          <div id="CLIVE" class="label label-success label-dismissible">0</div>
          | Reprovadas: 
          <div id="CDIE" class="label label-danger label-dismissible">0</div>
        </span> 

     </div>

</div>
```

You can see on the screenshot it's not centered, it works the way I want with the tag `<center>`, but I'm not using it, because I read it has been deprecated. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

[image]

If so, just simply add `text-align: center;` to your `.col-centered` style.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `.col-centered` is not used anymore?

Try `text-center`.

Have a look at [Bootstrap Classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-center).

Comment: That's a custom class, check the CSS. I've tried `.center-block` but it also didn't work.

Comment: My apologies, I see your problem now!  Just editing the CSS on Codepen.

Comment: Worked for me by adding 'text-center' to the column (after 'col-centered').

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-centered">
```

into this:

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-centered" style="text-align:center">
```

It also centers the inline content (i.e. the stuff inside the `span` element) not only the block elements.